# Can RTI Connext Open Community Source (OCS) be used?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I applied for, recieved, and installed [the OCS](https://www.rti.com/downloads/dds) distribution of RTI Connext. I was not able to run with it.

```
F:\dev\ros2bouncybin
$ local_setup.bat
[connext_cmake_module] Error: The expected location of the Connext environment setup script [[C:\Program Files\rti_connext_dds-5.3.1\resource\scripts\rtisetenv_x64Win64VS2017.bat]] does not exist. Support for Connext will not be available.
```

Is this supposed to be supported?

FIles that exist in `C:\Program Files\rti_connext_dds-5.3.1\resource\scripts`:

- rticommon.bat
- rticommon_config.bat

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301546/can-rti-connext-open-community-source-(ocs)-be-used?/) by [calvertdw](https://answers.ros.org/users/29941/calvertdw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2018-08-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like that you have only run a "host" installer but not any "target" bundle. You might want to double check to install at least one target bundle - e.g. something like "target-x64Win64VS2017.rtipkg".

And yes, you should be able to use the Connext OCS license - at the end of the day the code / API is the same and is only shipped under a different license (and potentially less functionality / tools).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2